# value too long for type character varying(10) when it is set to 255

Tags: django, heroku

In `models.py`

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.CharField(max_length = 35)
    name= models.CharField(max_length = 255)
```

I checked in `manage.py dbshell` within heroku, it says `character varying (35)` and `character varying (255)` respectively.

I'm running out of thoughts as to why it is like this. Local runs just fine. It is when I deploy it to heroku, I get this error. I've also tried deleting the entire db in heroku and restarting everything all over. That did not work either.

Comment: It happens when you save a photo right? With what values do you save it? Also, the id field is not necessary. Django creates its own id field automatically. (unless you want a specific field to be used as a primary key)

Comment: okay that id is not the photo_id, it's something else.  ID was probably a bad example. This is not a photo. This is just a string, getting a response from json and the number of characters are not that long. So im mind blown.

Comment: Provide the real model that you're using and the value that you use when saving the model. To me it simply seems like the value is too long for the constraint given in the model.